# Configure a bridge connection as a hub with netplan

Tags: networking, bridge, netplan

My current problem hits the limits of my basic networking skills.

In short : I "tapped" a server with multiple network interfaces on a network cable linking my router and my media center. I try to make this happen in a transparent way.

The network topology was :

```
Other machine (192.168.0.2) -- Router (192.168.0.1) -- Media center (192.168.0.3)
```

Now it's :

```
Other machine (192.168.0.2) -- Router (192.168.0.1) -- New server (192.168.0.4) -- Media center (192.168.0.3)
```

I set up a bridge connection on the server like so on netplan:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
    eno2:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eno1, eno2]
      addresses: [192.168.0.4/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        search: []
        addresses: [192.168.0.2]
```

The new server (192.168.0.4) can ping and ssh to the media center (192.168.0.3) and the router or the rest of the network (e.g. 192.168.0.2).

The media center (192.168.0.3) can ping and ssh the new server(192.168.0.4) but not the router nor the rest of the network. Conversely, the router and the rest of the network can not talk to the media center (192.168.0.3).

Can I achieve what I'm trying to do by defining [routes in the netplan config](https://netplan.io/examples#source-routing) (but I'm a bit out of my depth here, so help is welcome on how), or is it just not possible with this topology because I would have to somehow define the new server as a gateway to the media center in the routes of every machine of the network ?

Additional details :

```
me@newserver:~$ ip -br link
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
eno1             UP             00:22:19:cc:db:0c <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
eno2             UP             00:22:19:cc:db:0e <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
eno3             DOWN           00:22:19:cc:db:10 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> 
eno4             DOWN           00:22:19:cc:db:12 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> 
br0              UP             76:1b:8c:b8:3a:15 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
docker0          DOWN           02:42:17:43:24:12 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
me@newserver:~$ ip -br a
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
eno1             UP             
eno2             UP             
eno3             DOWN           
eno4             DOWN           
br0              UP             192.168.0.4/24 fe80::741b:8cff:feb8:3a15/64 
docker0          DOWN           172.17.0.1/16 fe80::42:17ff:fe43:2412/64 
me@newserver:~$ cat /proc/net/arp 
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
192.168.0.21     0x1         0x2         44:8a:5b:f1:d5:fb     *        br0
192.168.0.3      0x1         0x2         b8:27:eb:da:cb:20     *        br0
192.168.0.1      0x1         0x2         a0:1b:29:7d:d9:73     *        br0
192.168.0.2      0x1         0x2         d4:9a:20:c2:c8:c8     *        br0
me@newserver:~$ bridge link
2: eno1 state UP : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 19 
3: eno2 state UP : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 19 
me@newserver:~$ sudo iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Sun Jan 27 10:52:29 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [213193:40208006]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3463:1018938]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [766:58537]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [766:58537]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
[45:2724] -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[1:60] -A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jan 27 10:52:29 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Sun Jan 27 10:52:29 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [44978969:67464645682]
:FORWARD DROP [130478:14923761]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [23637250:1293021280]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
[130478:14923761] -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
[130478:14923761] -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[130478:14923761] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
[130478:14923761] -A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jan 27 10:52:29 2019
me@newserver:~$ sudo bridge monitor
a0:1b:29:7d:d9:74 dev eno1 master br0 
a0:1b:29:7d:d9:72 dev eno1 master br0 
Deleted a0:1b:29:7d:d9:74 dev eno1 master br0 stale
Deleted 78:67:d7:21:56:34 dev eno1 master br0 stale
78:67:d7:21:56:34 dev eno1 master br0 
a0:1b:29:7d:d9:74 dev eno1 master br0 
dev br0 port eno1 grp ff02::fb temp 
Deleted a0:1b:29:7d:d9:72 dev eno1 master br0 stale
Deleted 30:07:4d:3e:2f:bb dev eno1 master br0 stale
98:b6:e9:cd:fb:4a dev eno1 master br0 
Deleted a0:1b:29:7d:d9:74 dev eno1 master br0 stale
Deleted dev br0 port eno1 grp ff02::fb temp 
Deleted dev br0 port br0 grp ff02::fb temp
```

`bridge-netfilter` is not installed and there is no filtering that I know of (it's basically a fresh install + docker)

Comment: you should provide low level results from your settings, like `ip -br link`, `ip -br a`, `bridge link` , `ebtables-save`, `iptables-save -c` (in case [bridge-netfilter](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) is activated). If any filtering is activated, deactivate it. run tcpdump on each interface, `bridge monitor` to see what's going on etc

Comment: ok sorry i can't help any more, but those informations might perhaps give a clue to somebody else.

Comment: no problem and thanks, it was indeed a good clue !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible to achieve such a network setup, and the netplan configuration is correct. The problem actually came from iptable which dropped packets going over the bridge. [More details on the issue here](https://serverfault.com/questions/162366/iptables-bridge-and-forward-chain)

The fix is simply to accept packets on the bridge :

```
me@newserver:~$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p all -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

(and make the change permanent with :

```
me@newserver:~# iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

)

Comment: fwiw, this looks typically like bridge-netfilter activated: rules meant for layer 3 (ip/routing) having an effect on layer 2 (ethernet/switching).